# Double requirement given when trying to use pip install pandas

Tags: python, pandas, docker, pip

I want to build a Docker container using a Dockerfile containing `pip install -r requirements.txt`. pandas==0.22.0 is included in this requirements.txt file. Untill two days ago, the Docker container was perfectly build. Starting from yesterday, I receive an error:

> Double requirement given: numpy==1.12.1 from
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=6288d4e9cfea859e03dc82879539d029 (already in numpy==1.9.3 from
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=e1130c8f540a759d79ba5e8960f6915a,
>   name='numpy')

This error occurs both on Mac (Docker version: 18.03.0-ce-mac58 (23607)) and Ubuntu 16.04.3 (Docker version:  17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6).

I already tried to use different versions op pandas, to preinstall numpy, to remove pands from the requirements.txt file and install it seperately. As well as trying to install with `apt-get install python-pandas`. For the latter solution pandas v14 was installed, while I need at least v19.

Comment: This seems to be a "bug" in pip version 9.0.3. The installation goes well with pip version 9.0.1.

Comment: Were you able to find a filed bug on pip or setuptools for this? I have this issue on Travis CI too.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697

Comment: I did not find a filed bug. I just circumvented it by using an older pip version (9.0.1).

Comment: FYI pandas 0.21+ is not python 3.4 compatible (as discussed in the bug report linked above). I am currently able to install pandas 0.22 from source with python 3.4 with pip 9.0.3 but not 10.0. I have made a pull request to pandas to include a `python_requires` parameter in setup.py in future releases which should fix this.

Comment: Are you on pip-10 ? Try `pip install --no-build-isolation pandas`. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20723

Answer (score 8):

I finally found the solution for this in case of python3 or pip3

```sh
pip3 install pandas --no-build-isolation
```

Answer (score 6):

As of December 2020, in my case, upgrading `pip` to version 20.3 worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Might be of use to those who are working on Python3.4:

```
pip3 install 'pandas<0.21'
```

worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add a short description why your solution does solve the problem.

Comment: I was stuck at the same point while i was updating my code some time back from python2.7 to python3.4. The support for python3.4 is getting dropped as per the issue logged here  
https://github.com/mineo/mpd_pydb/commit/a6658fa955b68250a9cac5497cecd76aedd2d67a. In search for answers i found in one of the github issue links the above solution which is why i wrote the answer above. Let me give you the exact link. Here we go https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20723