# Cannot install pandas in a venv

Tags: python, linux, pandas, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

In a virtual env, after installing numpy without problems i run

```
pip3 install pandas
```

which returns:
EDIT:

```
 Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/01/803834bc8a4e708aedebb133095a88a4dad9f45bbaf5ad777d2bea543c7e/pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /home/bonzay/Desktop/Final_Project/venv/bin/python3.4 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-4pcvmc12 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=80044e51ec5bbf6c894ba0bc48d26a8c20a9ba629f4ca19ea26ecfcf87685f5f https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/10/79282747f9169f21c053c562a0baa21815a8c7879be97abd930dbcf862e8/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=0cb8b8625bfdcc2d43ea4b9cdba0b39b2b7befc04f3088897031082aa16ce186 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/25/1e1521e6ce2cf78ff4a8b06fbc2cd513ce004ec337000eddfe016fdf3fc6/Cython-0.28.2-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=85f7432776870d65639fed00f951a3c05ef1e534bc72a73cd1200d79b9a7d7d0 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bff36563f9d6a06a81ae232f49d2946c84c05e391a7dff057496033c79507860 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4eac5f2f624c5e7eecbdb51395ff39a099c48cab607a158f16f288c6fe39a2b3 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/ee/f65826b2880f67652c21326565b4c166c7cdb1019f84b82af65e625475cd/numpy-1.13.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=838e48df3703c8747f355cd6386e0680b906a2f7b2bbd304e8a2d531692484ce:
  Double requirement given: numpy==1.12.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4eac5f2f624c5e7eecbdb51395ff39a099c48cab607a158f16f288c6fe39a2b3 (already in numpy==1.9.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bff36563f9d6a06a81ae232f49d2946c84c05e391a7dff057496033c79507860, name='numpy')
```

Both numpy and pandas are installed globally with no problems. I tried re installing numpy, upgrading pip3, re installing setup tools. Nothing worked as expected, as i don't even understand the error message.

Comment: if you are IN your virtual environment, use pip install pandas not pip3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this which did the job for me:

```
Double requirement given when trying to use pip install pandas
```

[Double requirement given when trying to use pip install pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608953/double-requirement-given-when-trying-to-use-pip-install-pandas)

```
pip3 install 'pandas<0.21'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue! [`Ubuntu 16, python 3.5`] After creating my virtual environment using `python3 -m venv .env`, I could not install pandas in my .env virtual environment. This is how I fixed it:

The pip version of my virtualenv was `pip-8.1.1.` I ran the following command to upgrade it to `pip-20.0.2`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, ran `pip install pandas` to install pandas successfully within my virtual env!

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1 pandas-0.24.2 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3 six-1.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your problem. You should post what all you have done from the very beginning. Have you activated your virtualenv?
If you haven't this is how you can do it:

```
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score -1):

For an existing python3 virtual environment, we need to first reactivate the venv, here I show an example when I'm setting up vent for Sherlock, it miss 'pandas' module.

```
cd /home/user/Sherlock
source SherlockEnvironment/bin/activate
pip3 install pandas
```